# Sending data with HTTPS request and its cost

Tags: https, server

I need to send a message to an HTTPS server from an Arduino with a SIM900 module that has 10MB of data. The message to send contains a line of 10 numeric digits i.e. 5436278690. This message weighs 80 bit (or 10 bytes). I want to send it with a HTTPS request.

The question is:

**What is the total cost of sending this message through HTTPS request? How many bytes takes the HTTPS request from my data?**

HTTPS + message = how many bytes?

Comment: [read here about this](https://tls.ulfheim.net/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much network overhead does TLS add compared to a non-encrypted connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615882/how-much-network-overhead-does-tls-add-compared-to-a-non-encrypted-connection).

Answer: The total overhead to establish a new TLS session comes to about 6.5k bytes on average.

Comment: You will also need to be aware of what level of TLS/SSL you are using, and what **Primes** you are using that are compatible with the destination server.

Comment: If a make a new connection, can I connect back to the connection that I create or is it destroyed once you  stop using the connection?